# How do you obtain all the ILLinePLots contained in the ILPlotCube in ILNumerics?

Tags: ilnumerics

If I use this expression Scene.Find().Find(), it gets me the first line object contained in the plotcube. In otherwise I can loop through the objects contained in the plotcube and find each lineplot?

Comment: Are you sure, you mean 'Scene.Find().Find()' ? I must admit, I still dont really get the question yet.

Comment: what i meant was that you use the scene property of ILpanel to find the ilplotcube and assign it to a reference and then you use that reference to find the ilineplot.

Comment: Sounds like a working solution? Which problems are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

do you mean ... ?

```
foreach (var lineplot in scene.Find<ILLinePlot>()) {
    // do with lineplot here 
}
```